# How To Get Name From NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I have a NSFetchRequest to search of core data entities.  It finds them fine, but I want to set the cell's text to the entity's `name` attribute.

I currently have this but I am setting the object itself to the title, instead of the name attribute, how can I fix this?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
self.routineArray = results;
[fetchRequest release];

cell.textLabel.text = [self.routineArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.routineArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
```

**EDIT**

If your `Routine` instances are in `routineArray` (given that name, I suppose) :

```
// get the Routine instance
Routine *r = [self.routineArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// now you got your instance, set anything you want on r...
// ...
// and then set its name as the text for textLabel using previous instruction
```

Comment: Nice, that works.  But is there a way I can do this so that I can actually retrieve the `Routine` objects? So that I can modify them as needed.

Comment: if your `Routine` instances are stored in `routineArray`, of course there is. I will edit.